# Поток, который спит и просыпается через каждые 30 секунд

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, многопоточность

Как написать поток Thread на С#, изначально который спит и просыпается через каждые 30 секунд??

Comment: Почитайте Albahari [Treading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: Поскольку внизу комментарии закончились, отвечу VlaD про volatile здесь:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Самый базовый пример. Подгоните дальше под свои нужды.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace sdgfhsffdfg
{
  class Program
  {

    static Thread th;
    static Boolean stopIt = false;

    static void TheThread()
    {

        while (!stopIt)
        {
             Thread.Sleep(30000);
             doMyActions();
        }  
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TheThread));     
        th.Start();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно защитить lock'ом обращение к `stopIt` (ну или хотя бы memory barrier). И ещё между установкой флага `stopIt` и завершением потока может пройти 30 секунд, это многовато. И ещё «`new ThreadStart`» можно выкинуть.

Comment: спс, помогло

Comment: 2 VladD

+ А есть ли смысл в чтении ставить lock? Там будет неразрывная операция.
+ Да-да. Бок. Каюсь. Оправдание - писал без среды, по памяти.
+ Ну по хорошему - да. Там нужен или счетчик, или если уж совсем красиво то семафор и wait с таймером. Но это ухудшит читабельность и понимабельность кода.
+ Реально можно. Прикольно ))
+ Да.
+ :-P

Comment: @SilverIce: Смысл lock'а вот в чём. У каждого из потоков имеет право быть своё представление о значении переменных в памяти. Например, на это влияет несброшенный кеш многопроцессорной системы. Синхронизация происходит не при любом доступе, а лишь при наличии memory barrier'а. Так что нужен либо явный memory barrier, либо lock (который внутри тоже ставит memory barrier). Литературы с техническими подробностями не так уж много, например вот [эта статья](http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf), особенно глава 6. (Там правда про C++, но применимо и к C#.) Общее правило: ...

Comment: @SilverIce: ... если доступ к переменной происходит из разных потоков, неважно, на чтение или на запись, её необходимо защищать или memory barrier'ом, или (что проще) lock'ом.

Comment: > если доступ к переменной происходит из разных потоков, неважно, на чтение или на запись, её необходимо защищать или memory barrier'ом, или (что проще) lock'ом.

Атомарность для типов размера <= sizeof(void*) уже отменили?

Comment: @Flammable: атомарность тут не при чём. Перечитайте ещё раз статью Александреску по ссылке из комментария выше: речь идёт о модели памяти. Изменения, видимые внутри одного потока, будут _гарантировано_ видны в другом потоке **только** после memory barrier'а, точка. Атомарность здесь не играет никакой роли, она влияет лишь на _консистентность_: с ней гарантируется лишь что другой поток _ни при каких условиях_ не увидит частичного изменения. Но не гарантируется, что увидит изменение как таковое. Окей?

Comment: > Изменения, видимые внутри одного потока, будут гарантировано видны в другом потоке только после memory barrier'а, точка

Если вы о кэшировании, то придумана специальная штука: volatile.

Comment: @Flammable: У Александреску там и про `volatile` есть. Так вот, в той же статье разбирается, что семантика `volatile` не означает memory barrier, так что не поможет.

---
Вот вам ещё пример: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword

> applying volatile doesn’t prevent a write followed by a read from being swapped

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, вы слишком усложняете простые штуки. Зачем в контексте обсуждаемой задачи вам нужны локи и барьеры?

Comment: @Flammable: потому что переменная `stopIt` записывается в одном потоке, а читается в другом? Многопоточное программирование? как мне кажется, никогда не было простой штукой.

Comment: > потому что переменная stopIt записывается в одном потоке, а читается в другом?
И? В отличие от Александреску, который разбирал реализацию синглтона, где помимо *проверки* нужно, грубо говоря, выполнить еще кое-что, вам нужно только установить флаг в одном потоке и только проверить его в другом. volatile bool здесь достаточно (ну waitable timer, если очень нужно завершать спящий поток сразу после установки флага).

Comment: @Flammable: А Albahari пишет, я же цитировал:

> applying volatile doesn’t prevent a write followed by a read from being swapped

То есть если сначала записалось значение, а потом прочиталось в другом потоке, то процессору будет разрешено поменять местами эффекты, т.е. прочитано будет старое значение.

А давайте не я буду давать опровергающие примеры, а вы — подтверждающие, а? Найдите место в документации, которое утверждает, что volatile гарантирует одинаковые значения переменной в пишущем и читающем потоках.

Вот вам ещё статья Эрика по теме: http://tiny.cc/wx8m4w

Comment: И началось месилово))

С точки зрения педантизма - да. VladD - прав и писать нужно именно так.

С точки зрения здравого смысла - в экранировании чтения нет никакого смысла, достаточно экранировать запись. По факту lock'a при записи произойдет столь желанная "синхронизация", а код чтения в любом раскладе попадет или до этого радостного события и получит старые данные или после и гарантированно получит новые - тут уж как повезет.

Во-вторых, это все имеет реальный смысл когда мы говорим о С++ которая генерирует тонкий машинный код и сихронизация лежит на кодере.

Comment: Как поведет себя CLR - никому кроме Билла не известно. Но в общем виде работу с памятью она берет на себя.

Далее. Реальные проблемы со значениями в кешах разных процессоров могуть быть только на мультипроцессорных системах причем речь шла только о серверных.

Хотя лично мне было интересно и даже чуть-чуть полезно. Спасибо :)

Comment: @SilverIce: ну, это не махалово, мы ж не злобно и сто лет друг друга виртуально знаем.

По делу: экранирование чтения тоже нужно, т.к. в читающем потоке может быть закешированное значение (например, оптимизатор оставил его в регистре, или кеш не сбросился). Barrier на запись гарантирует, что записанное значение «провалится» в память, но не что будет «подобрано» читающим потоком/процессором.

---
JIT-компилятор по факту генерирует код, сравнимый с кодом C++, на простых структурах. А что, у кого-то ещё не многопроцессорный комп?

Comment: 2 VladD

> Найдите место в документации, которое утверждает, что volatile
> гарантирует одинаковые значения переменной в пишущем и читающем
> потоках.

Из вами же данной ссылки на "статью Эрика":

Comment: Цитата, млин:

       In C#, "volatie" means not only "make sure that the compiler 
       and the jitter do not perform any code reordering or register 
       caching optimizations on this variable". It also means "tell the
       processors to do whatever it is they need to do to ensure that 
       I am reading the latest value, even if that means halting other 
       processors and making them synchronize main memory with their caches".

Comment: @SilverIce: а следующий абзац? :-)

> Actually, that last bit is a lie. [skip] In fact they do not actually guarantee that every processor stops what it is doing and updates caches to/from main memory. [] Certain operations such as [] entering a lock [] introduce stronger guarantees about observation of ordering.
>
> Volatile fields are a sign that you are doing something downright crazy: you're attempting to read and write the same value on two different threads without putting a lock in place. Locks guarantee that memory read or modified inside the lock is observed to be consistent []